# How to do Intersect on list of strings created from String.Split

Tags: c#, linq

I create 3 list of strings by doing String.Split(). After that when I do an Intersect on those lists the results are not what I expect.
Code 1 (not working)

```
    string a = "AID, BID";
    string b = "[vs|AID|1365]";
    string c = "[vs|BID|1365]";

    List<string> la = new List<string>();
    string[] k = a.Split(",".ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    foreach (string p in k)
    {
        la.Add(p);
    }
    //la.AddRange(k.ToList());
    List<string> lb = new List<string>();
    string[] kk = b.Split("|".ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    foreach (string p in kk)
    {
        lb.Add(p);
    }
    //lb.AddRange(kk.ToList());
    List<string> lc = new List<string>();
    string[] kkk = c.Split("|".ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    foreach (string p in kkk)
    {
        lc.Add(p);
    }
    //lc.AddRange(kkk.ToList());

    var t = la.Intersect(lb, StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
    Debug.WriteLine(t.Count()); //Prints 1 -- RIGHT
    var tt = la.Intersect(lc, StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
    Debug.WriteLine(tt.Count()); //Prints 0 -- WRONG!!!
```

I tried the AddRange and that did not work either. Another thing I noticed is if I altered the sequence of AID & BID in "string a" assignment, then intersect finds BID but not AID. Not sure why?

A hard-coded version of above routine works fine

```
        List<string> la = new List<string>(); la.Add("AID"); la.Add("BID");
        List<string> lb = new List<string>(); lb.Add("[vs"); lb.Add("AID"); lb.Add("1365]");
        List<string> lc = new List<string>(); lc.Add("[vs"); lc.Add("BID"); lc.Add("1365]");
        var t = la.Intersect(lb, StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
        Debug.WriteLine(t.Count()); //Prints 1.
        var tt = la.Intersect(lc, StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
        Debug.WriteLine(tt.Count());//Prints 1.
```

UPDATE:
Below is the code I ended up with.

```
    string a = "AID, BID";
    string b = "[vs|AID|1365]";
    string c = "[vs|BID|1365]";

    List<string> tla = a.Split(",".ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                        .Select(s => s.Trim()).ToList();
    List<string> tlb = b.Split("|".ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                        .Select(s => s.Trim()).ToList();
    List<string> tlc = c.Split("|".ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                        .Select(s => s.Trim()).ToList();

    var t = tla.Intersect(tlb, StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
    var tt = tla.Intersect(tlc, StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you mean

```
string[] k = a.Split(", ".ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

?
Because there is a space in your source string:

```
string a = "AID, BID";
```

By the way you could've just written this as

```
var la = a.Split(", ".ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
var lb = b.Split("|".ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
var lc = c.Split("|".ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

var t = la.Intersect(lb, StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase).ToList();
var tt = la.Intersect(lc, StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase).ToList();
```

You don't need intermediate lists because LINQ also has `Intersect` method.
But it'd be worth caching the results, so you should call `ToList` for the final items.

Comment: Thanks, that was it. I guess I should have looked closer at the list in debugger. Shall mark as answer after "9 minutes". :)

Comment: @rjv_rnjn you could also remove superfluous white space by trimming the substrings after splitting.

Comment: Thanks @phoog. Nice suggestion. Modified my post to show the final code.

Comment: @Dan Abramov: Saw your edit late. I never intended to get those loops, it was just to show a step by step comparison of the code not working and the exact same code with hard coded values working. Thanks again.